# Preserve link in php form

Tags: php, forms

I've created a form that sends two email:
1. To me
2. A confirmation email to the user with a link to some other information

```
<?php
$to ='email@email.com';
$subject ="This is My Subject";
$header="From: $firstName $lastName <$email>";
$message = "Name: $firstName $lastName \n\nPhone: $phone \n\nEmail: $email";
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

if ( $send_contact ) {
echo "Super fun message";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

$to1 = $email;
$subject1 ="This is my email Subject";
$header1="From: email@email.com <email@email.com>";
$message1 = "Thanks check out this <a href="http://link.com" title="">link</a>.";
$send_contact1=mail($to1,$subject1,$message1,$header1);
```

?>

Problem, I think, is the syntax for the link in $message1 isn't correct... I just can't get it right.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the quotation mark just before the link match the one at the start on $message1, change them to single quotation marks and you should be fine.

```
$message1 = "Thanks check out this <a href='www.link.com' title=''>link</a>."
```

Comment: Thanks! That is closer - The page shows up and not just a white screen.. but here's what the email looks like:
"Thanks check out this <a href='http://link.com' title=''>link</a>."
It just displays the code, not a link. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the quotes, hence confusing the interpreter and resulting into error. Proper way to use in such cases is first ""(double quotes) and then ''(Single quotes) .

The above example is good one. You can refer to that.